# Selecting active Meteor Subscriptions

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm going through the "Discover Meteor" book, and I've come across a question I'm having trouble reconciling. My question being, how does Meteor know how to activate which publications to subscribe to?

This is my publications.js server side

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(limit){
    return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: limit});
});

Meteor.publish('newPosts', function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: limit});
});

Meteor.publish('bestPosts', function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {votes: -1, submitted: -1}, limit: limit});
});

Meteor.publish('singlePost', function(id) {
  return id && Posts.find(id);
});


Meteor.publish('comments', function(postId) {
  return Comments.find({postId: postId});
});

Meteor.publish('notifications', function() {
  return Notifications.find({userId: this.userId});
});
```

Then the subscriptions located in main.js

```
newPostsHandle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('newPosts', 10);
bestPostsHandle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('bestPosts', 10);

postHandle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('posts', 10);

Deps.autorun(function() {  
  Meteor.subscribe('comments', Session.get('currentPostId'));
})

Meteor.subscribe('notifications');
```

So how does meteor know which subscriptions are necessary? Am I subscribed to every subscription no matter where I am in the app? I figure the router is at play, but I don't know if I clearly see what router is doing to manage subscriptions?

Comment: Have you removed package `autopublish` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor actives the subscriptions you tell it to. So a subscription like:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts');
```

Will subscribe to `posts` as soon as the client starts running, and will always keep the subscription open. On the other hand, if you have an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) like:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('comments', Session.get('currentPostId'));
});
```

The subscription will again activate when the client starts, but it will rerun whenever the `currentPostId` session variable is updated. Note that a common idiom is to initiate some subscriptions as soon as the user logs in. For example:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.userId())
    Meteor.subscribe('friends');
});
```

In all of the above cases, the subscriptions are activated independent of where the user is in the app. It's extremely common to use iron-router's `waitOn` hook to activate the subscriptions relevent to the current route. For example:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('dashboard', {
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('news');
    }
  });
});
```

Whenever the user navigates to the `dashboard` route, he will also subscribe to `news`. When he navigates away, the subscription will stop (with some caveats) and new subscriptions will start depending on how the router is configured. Side note: [Subscriptions Manager](http://meteorhacks.com/subscriptions-manager-is-here.html) is an interesting optimization to the problem of constantly starting and stopping your subscriptions when navigating between routes.

Finally, I'll note that it's perfectly reasonable to have a mix of global and route-specific subscriptions. Feel free to mix and match as appropriate for your application.

Comment: Thanks David.Maybe a little off topic, but is it reasonable to have all these subscriptions active at once? What do you consider too much data persisting on the client side?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no precise answer to this question. In our main app, we have maybe 10-15 subscriptions/user going at once (mix of global and route-based). A first-order approximation of subscription pain will be based on the number of documents subscribed to and their modification frequency. It may be that some penalty is paid for the number of active subscriptions but I haven't noticed that in practice. Like everything in software engineering,  I wouldn't optimize early. Try doing what makes the most sense and then [measure](https://kadira.io/) your performance in production.